# Adding moving average column to dataframe per indexed category variable

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, indexing

I have a pandas dataframe timeseries weight for over 100 scales named per "short_id". I am having trouble figuring out the best way to apply a moving filter for each scale's weight data to remove outliers.

Here is a sample of the data:

```
Out[159]:
    published_at        short_id weight
0   2017-11-08 16:03:36 INT16   50.35
1   2017-11-08 16:02:43 INT1    45.71
2   2017-11-08 16:02:10 NOT11   35.52
3   2017-11-08 16:01:07 INT7    50.03
4   2017-11-08 16:00:23 INT3    47.04
```

converting the dataframe into a dictionary per "short_id" and apply moving filter per dict item did not work out, nor did converting the data to a "wide" format from "long" (using pandas.pivot_table).

It seems like it could be possible in one line using groupy.by then .apply the rolling function:

```
  df['MovingFilt'] = df.groupby('short_id')['weight'].apply(pd.rolling(6).median())
```

but receive an error: TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index...This is because sometimes there is weight data at the same time for certain scales, but not usually.

Is this the best way to approach the problem?:

Creating new dataframes per 'short_id' then using seems not pythonic enough, although it runs fine

```
INT16['MovingFilt'] = pd.Series.rolling(INT16['weight'], window=6, center=True).median()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because you wrote the groupby wrong

```
df['MovingFilt'] = df.groupby('short_id')['weight'].rolling(6).median().values
```

Comment: Thank you, i added the missing parenthesis and updated post. I suspect the problem lies in the sometimes overlapping timestamps